# Mercedes E320 where is the starter relay

Tags: starter, mercedes-benz, relay, e320

The ESP says it is malfunctioning. in a 2001 Mercedes e320, will that affect starting and where is the starter relay

Comment: ESP "Electronic Stability Program" error should have no effect on the starter relay under most conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Relay Is designated L in the image below, there is a fuse for the relay and it is #59

[image]

[image]

.

[Source](https://fuse-box.info/mercedes-benz/mercedes-benz-e-class-w211-2003-2009-fuses-and-relay)